# When my Selenium test tries to connect to the browser, it fails

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

When I try to create a web browser in my Python Selenium test, it fails.  The message suggests that the Firefox and Geckodriver versions do not match.  They are both at the most current.

Has anyone else encountered this, and knows what to do?

```
Terminal window: 
(python-tdd-book-ygR1jeFn-py3.7) rickhedin@Ricks-MBP python-tdd-book % python manage.py test functional_tests
   . . . 
  File "/Users/rickhedin/work/201106/python-tdd-book/functional_tests/tests2.py", line 25, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
   . . . 
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Possible firefox version mismatch. You must use GeckoDriver instead for Firefox 48+. Profile Dir: /var/folders/qs/89rdcgzj42d0nrz_v7yqpqk00000gn/T/tmp0_k9zq4q If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

Geckodriver version:
(python-tdd-book-ygR1jeFn-py3.7) rickhedin@Ricks-MBP python-tdd-book % geckodriver -V
geckodriver 0.28.0 (c00d2b6acd3f 2020-11-03 16:29 +0200)

Firefox version: 
82.0.2 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your driver matches your browser's version. For example with chrome (for me), if my browser is version 86.0, I need a chrome driver that is also similar, or else it wouldn't work. You said that they're both the current version, but are their current version the same?

Comment: Hi.   Well, no.   geckodriver is 0.28.0, and Firefox is 82.0.2    But they are both the newest version.

Comment: according to [this link](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html) those two are compatible, so maybe you can try to see if you're using selenium version 3.11+ (as mention on the page)

Comment: Ah!   I'll do that!   (After I walk my dogs.   They're crossing their legs.)

Comment: My selenium seems to be 3.141.0 which is bigger than 3.11   (python-tdd-book-ygR1jeFn-py3.7) rickhedin@Ricks-MBP python-tdd-book % poetry show selenium
name         : selenium
version      : 3.141.0
description  : Python bindings for Selenium

Comment: I thought (3.14 Python) in the versions table meant Python of version 3.14 .   But Python is only at 3.9 right now.   It must be that for Python, the selenium version has to be at 3.14)